# SFDC DKIM Setup - Production or Sandbox?

Tags: dkim

Cannot figure out this via SFDC documentation. Need someone who have setup this before to advise.

Basically we want to enable DKIM for our SFDC org. In testing Sandbox and production, the from email address is using the same email domain. For example, "test@abc.com" for sandbox and "contact@abc.com" in production.

**Question**: shall we setup DKIM in both sandbox and production or just need to setup in production since sandbox and production are actually using the same domain "abc.com"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DKIM is domain based, not org based, so only one is necessary. Also, be aware of the following:

- You can have only one active DKIM key per domain name.
- You can have multiple active DKIM keys if:

  - Your company sends mail from multiple domains, or
  - You use subdomains under your organizational domain and specify domain matching at the subdomain level.

**References**

- [Considerations for Creating DKIM Keys](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_considerations_dkim.htm&type=5)
- [Sign outbound emails with DomainKeys (DKIM)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrGUAA0)

Comment: so the recommendation is to setup in production org directly, right?

Comment: @kaoZ Scheduling a weekend for updating the records and performing [validation](https://dkimcore.org/tools/dkimrecordcheck.html) would be a must in a production only scenario. A domain and subdomain setup would allow you to have the sandbox mapping independently testable, which would be safer.

Comment: It's possible to have multiple DKIM key per domain name, please could you correct your answer @PaulSweatte?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple DKIM records on a single domain is possible by creating multiple DKIM selectors on that domain, with each selector pointing to a DKIM record.

More info [here](https://dmarcly.com/blog/can-i-have-multiple-dkim-records-on-my-domain)

So we can have sandboxes and production org with their own dkims keys.
And indeed it's not possible to import one key to another org as mention [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381186&type=1).